# Windows Http Server API HTTPS Server

Tags: c++, visual-studio, https

I want to setup a HTTPS Server with Windows Server API in c++, I used the example code, it is working fine with HTTP, but I just can not make it to work with HTTPS.

(I do not want client side SSL I only one it to be HTTPS )

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364640(v=vs.85).aspx

I tryed with "HttpSetServiceConfiguration HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_SSL_SET" here is my try:

```
PHTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_SSL_SET p_ssl_settings = new HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_SSL_SET();
p_ssl_settings->KeyDesc.pIpPort = new SOCKADDR();
inet_pton(AF_INET, "0.0.0.0", p_ssl_settings->KeyDesc.pIpPort);
p_ssl_settings->ParamDesc.SslHashLength = 40;
p_ssl_settings->ParamDesc.pSslHash = "dec5a1a952967a613f27dec98ab78a248cd9f782";
p_ssl_settings->ParamDesc.AppId = {0x4dbfb575, 0xe1ef, 0x4239,{0x9a, 0x1d, 0xe9, 0x4c, 0xf8, 0x4d, 0xc2, 0x2d}};
p_ssl_settings->ParamDesc.pSslCertStoreName = nullptr;
p_ssl_settings->ParamDesc.DefaultCertCheckMode = 0;
p_ssl_settings->ParamDesc.DefaultRevocationFreshnessTime = 0;
p_ssl_settings->ParamDesc.DefaultRevocationUrlRetrievalTimeout = 0;
p_ssl_settings->ParamDesc.pDefaultSslCtlIdentifier = nullptr;
p_ssl_settings->ParamDesc.pDefaultSslCtlStoreName = nullptr;
p_ssl_settings->ParamDesc.DefaultFlags = HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_SSL_FLAG_NEGOTIATE_CLIENT_CERT;


const auto retcode = HttpSetServiceConfiguration(
    hReqQueue,
    HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_ID::HttpServiceConfigSSLCertInfo,
    p_ssl_settings,
    sizeof HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_SSL_SET,
    nullptr
);

if (retcode != NO_ERROR) {
    throw exception(string("HttpSetServiceConfiguration failed with " + to_string(retcode)).c_str());
}
```

But when I run the code get error:87 which is the bad parameter error but to me the parameters seams fine.

On this web page it is mentiond that the HANDLE must be zero: 
(ServiceHandle [in] Reserved. Must be zero.)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364503(v=vs.85).aspx

but when I pass a nullptr or a HANDLE variable which value is zero I get error code '6' (The handle is invalid.) so I am not sure

I tryed with "netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:50001 certhash=de... appid{...}

but I can not get this right because I get error 1312:
(my be my appid is bad, but I dont know how to get it for my visual studio c++ .exe)
A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

I tryed with "https://localhost:50001/" as an URL.

How can I do it right with c++ "HttpSetServiceConfiguration" or netsh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I found out the problem I used HttpInitialize(Version, Flags, pReserved) function wrongly and I only give it the 'HTTP_INITIALIZE_SERVER' while I should have added ' HTTP_INITIALIZE_CONFIG' as well so this was the main problem although it is hard to figure it out from the error code 87 only.

Original:

```
HttpInitialize(HTTPAPI_VERSION_1, HTTP_INITIALIZE_SERVER, nullptr);
```

Fixed:

```
HttpInitialize(HTTPAPI_VERSION_1, HTTP_INITIALIZE_CONFIG | HTTP_INITIALIZE_SERVER, nullptr);
```